# JavaScript not working while using external script file but working internally

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am implementing JavaScript validations for required fields in a form in an ASP.NET Web Application.

I am getting the ClientID of the control to be validated and extracting the value from it and checking whether it is null:

```
function validate()
{
    if(document.getElementById('<%=textbox1.clientID %>').value=="")
    {
        alert('mandatory');
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am validating on client click of a button. This code works pretty fine when the above function is placed in the same page.

But when I place it in an external file and call it, the code is not working.

It is calling the function in external .js file and throwing an error message like *object not found at document.geteleementByid() line*.

Comment: try including javascript and the end of the page... or ensure that javascript run after complete page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add parameter to your method. And while u're calling external method add the parameter '<%=textbox1.clientID %>' like below.

```
<javascript>
     var param = document.getElementById('<%=textbox1.clientID %>').value;
     validate(param);
</javascript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code is calling a server-side property `textbox1.ClientID`. In order to put your code in a .js file, you will need to call that server-side property somewhere in your .aspx file and send the value you get to your JavaScript function:

```
function callValidation() {
    return validation('<%= textbox1.ClientID %>');
}
```

Then your .js file would contain the actual validation method:

```
function validate(elementId)
{
    if(document.getElementById(elementId).value=="")
    {
        alert('mandatory');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what should be the type of input parameter for the function in the external js file is it object ?

Comment: In JavaScript, everything is var. In this case, we're passing a string (see those ' characters?)

Comment: Here, my doubt is how to recieve that value?

Comment: There you go, on a silver platter.

Comment: Thanks for your patient answering..it worked like a charm..saved me time

Comment: Hey sorry to interrupt you again..i was getting error at this line again..  onclientclick="return callvalidation();" . The error message is Object Expected..please help.

Comment: It couldn't find a function called "callvalidation" - check spelling/capitalization, and make sure there are no JavaScript errors that are keeping the JS from compiling